# How to use GA4 in GTM with UA tags?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

we start implementing GA4. We are having many UA-tags in GTM.
So far I have added a GA4 tag with the GA4 measurement-id in GTM. In GA4 I am alreade receiving some data.

Now I wonder if I have to rewrite every UA-tag 'Google Analytics: Universal Analytics' as 'Google Analytics: GA4-Event'?

In Goggle analytics it says to use the migration assistent. but when going deeper it doesn't looks so simple.
We have more then 20 UA-Tags in GTM. So I really have to adjust them all manually to GA4?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, for all the events you want to continue capturing in GA4, you will need to create a new GA4 event tag. As far as the migration assistant, I have seen spotty reviews at best and usually see the recommendation of just starting from scratch.

In my personal experience, this gives you a chance to trim some of the bloat that has occurred while managing your Universal Analytics over the years. You may find that a percentage of your tags aren't being used, or the data within Google Analytics isn't being leveraged enough to justify the capture.

Comment: Thank you. I have created a new GA4 tag for the UA tags where I find an appropriate event in GA4. I wonder if I can use the same trigger. So far I have done so.

Comment: You should be able to use the same triggers as the underlying site hasn't changed; only your analytics engine.